# parsename is not working when using string from function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Parsename is working when directly using string or returning static value from the function. But when I returning select value with dot from the function. its not working. I am not able to figure out the issue.

```
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTimeLine](
                [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
                [Field1] [nchar](250) NOT NULL,
                [Value] [smalldatetime] NULL,
                [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
            )

           INSERT INTO [TestTimeLine] VALUES(10,'TestDate',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
    CREATE FUNCTION TestFunction()
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
            DECLARE @R NVARCHAR(MAX)
            SELECT TOP 1 @R=CAST(DATENAME(month,value) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(value) AS VARCHAR) + '.' +CONVERT(varchar,value,101) + '. ' + LTRIM(Field1)
             FROM   [TestTimeLine]          
             WHERE  UserId = 10
             RETURN @R
    END


select dbo.TestFunction()
select PARSENAME(dbo.TestFunction(),2)
```

**Working**

```
select PARSENAME('January 2015.01/05/2015. TestDate',2)
```

**NotWorking** -- Returns NULL

```
select PARSENAME(dbo.TestFunction(),2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Issue.

Issue is `[nchar]` datatype.

After Changing to 'Varchar' datatype. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parameter 2 to 1.

```
select PARSENAME(dbo.TestFunction(),1)
```

For more details refer to: 
[More Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that return value of `dbo.TestFunction()` is incorrect identifier - it exceeds maximal length limitation for object identifiers in SQL Server. Your sample return value has many trailing spaces which cause this situation.

In general, this is not good idea to use `PARSENAME` for your purpose because you are using the function not for its initial purpose so you have all side effects which are not predictable from one SQL Server version to another. Use ordinary string functions in your case.